# Why doesn't django-social-auth take into account the next variable when logging in?

Tags: django, django-socialauth

If I'm going directly to a page (which requires a user to be logged in) without having logged in, Django's authentication framework takes me to the login page and then redirects to the page I had requested based on the value in the `next` variable.

However with `django-social-auth` is this not the case? I've implemented `django-social-auth` and I can see that the `next` variable in the URL is populated correctly. But when I finally login using Facebook, it re-directs me to the URL specified in the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` variable.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Which version are you using? A bug related to `next` was fixed some time ago.

Comment: `0.6.9` carries that fix, are you able to reproduce it using `0.7.0`?

Comment: Hmmm ok. Yes I just uninstalled 0.6.9 and installed 0.7.0 and the problem remains.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

how is the code of your template?
You put the url call as follows:

```
{% url socialauth_begin 'facebook' %}{% if request.GET.next %}?next={{ request.GET.next }}{% endif %}
```

Comment: The code in your templates must have the `?next=` paramter, otherwise DSA won't get it. Did you tried doing `{% if request.GET.next %}...{% endif %}` as @Gileno detailed? In that case, it's possible that the `request` is not present in the template context.

Comment: Oops...I have no idea how I missed updating this. Yes his solution works perfectly fine. Not sure what I was doing wrong earlier. Apologies for the confusion.